# Calculate nearest neighbors using a nxn matrix

Tags: python, numpy, nearest-neighbor

Supposed I have nxn  T random matrix, how can I find nearest neighbors element of the matrix?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your image description, my usual way is to generate an index matrix, calculate the Euclidean distance between each element and a given position, and then judge whether the distance is 1:

```
>>> m = np.random.rand(5, 5)
>>> m
array([[0.15993681, 0.34212   , 0.27103587, 0.47880503, 0.92797347],
       [0.56698489, 0.16124083, 0.63037649, 0.79914445, 0.55247301],
       [0.05826773, 0.26793143, 0.62384919, 0.8248818 , 0.75127237],
       [0.38831836, 0.51175059, 0.70764241, 0.08915257, 0.63465847],
       [0.17459285, 0.74014131, 0.42850117, 0.54282051, 0.61795445]])
>>> ii, jj = np.indices(m.shape)
>>> i, j = 2, 3
>>> mask = np.hypot(ii - i, jj - j) == 1
>>> mask
array([[False, False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False,  True, False],
       [False, False,  True, False,  True],
       [False, False, False,  True, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False]])
>>> m[mask]
array([0.79914445, 0.62384919, 0.75127237, 0.08915257])
```

The advantage of this method are:

- it is usually not slow, unless your matrix is very large, but there are still workarounds.
- you needn't to consider some boundary conditions. For example, the target position is at the edge of the matrix.
- it has strong expansibility. For example, if you redefine the neighbor as an element with a distance of less than or equal to 2, or an element in a circle around itself, you can achieve your expectation with only a little modification.

For a large matrix, considering the boundary conditions, you can implement it through such a function:

```
>>> def neighbor_indices(arr, pos, dist_func=np.hypot, dist=1):
...     start = [max(p - dist, 0) for p in pos]
...     shape = [s - p for s, p in zip(arr.shape, start)]
...     indices = np.indices(shape)
...     ii, jj = [i + s for i, s in zip(indices, start)]
...     i, j = pos
...     mask = dist_func(ii - i, jj - j) == dist
...     return ii[mask], jj[mask]
...
>>> neighbor_indices(m, (2, 3))
(array([1, 2, 2, 3]), array([3, 2, 4, 3]))
>>> neighbor_indices(m, (3, 4))
(array([2, 3, 4]), array([4, 3, 4]))
>>> neighbor_indices(m, (-1, -1))
(array([], dtype=int32), array([], dtype=int32))
>>> neighbor_indices(m, (5, 5))
(array([], dtype=int32), array([], dtype=int32))
>>> neighbor_indices(m, (2, 3), dist=2)
(array([0, 2, 4]), array([3, 1, 3]))
>>> neighbor_indices(m, (2, 3), lambda i, j: np.maximum(np.abs(i), np.abs(j)))
(array([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]), array([2, 3, 4, 2, 4, 2, 3, 4]))
```

Comment: Instead of i values and j values in tuple , how can I get (i,j) for each TRUE value as an output ?

Comment: Referring to the first example, use them as indexes of the array: `m[neighbor_indices(m, (2, 3))]` @VipulRai

Comment: In my case I have T matrix and  after getting nearest neighbors then apply some condition like, If T [ i, j ] >0.5 then change the nearest neighbor value by 1 (T = T_(nearest_position) +1)

Comment: `if T[i, j] > 0.5: T[neighbor_indices(T, (i, j))] += 1`. If you have more questions, I think you need to ask another question separately instead of continuing to ask questions in the comment area.